# Presocratics from the view of mathematicians and physicists

Tags: mathematicians, philosophy-of-science, physicists, book-recommendation

I am interested in a book that has all the fragments of pre-socratics but the notes etc. in the translation are from a mathematician or physicist relating with how each point affected the evolution of mathematics or physics. Case in point Zeno's arguments.
Is there such an edition?

Comment: [Carlos Rovelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlo_Rovelli) wrote a popular science book on [Anaximander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaximander), however I don't think you will find what you are looking for there or elsewhere.  Also note that the fragments we have are fragments of the testimonia of later writers' commentaries on the presocratics.  Often the fragments are from commentaries on earlier commentaries on the presocratics. For examples, fragments concerning Zeno by Simplicius are from Simplicius' *Commentary on Aristotle's Physics*.

Comment: @nwr: by the way how come we ended up getting them as fragments and from 3rd sources? They never wrote their theories and it was all word of mouth?

Comment: "They never wrote their theories..." Why so? We have only fragments of the original texts, but for sure there were texts. See e.g. [Democritus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democritus#Works)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA My reference (Patricia Curd, *A Presocratics Reader*) cites no surviving fragments of Democritus, only second and third hand fragments.

Comment: @Jim The basic problems is that when they wrote, they wrote on papyrus and clay tablets, neither of which are suitable for a long life.

Comment: @Jim Another point to consider is that there were a limited number of qualified scribes.  Therefore, when new and presumably "better" texts appears, they would limit their efforts to copying these.  For example, once Euclid's Elements appeared, scribes eventually saw no reason to continue to copy older mathematical texts.

Comment: @nwr: I suppose your last point is of a general nature because I find it hard to believe that they would purposely prefer to spend effort on something else than e.g. text from Parmenidis and hence the later would disappear

Comment: @Jim Like many (if not all presocratics), Parmenides wrote in poetic verse, employing Homeric hexameters and Homeric imagery - especially from *Odyssey*.  This style of writing was superseded  by the rhetorical style of later Greek philosophers.  This may have contributed to a loss of interest in copying the original texts.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The SEP article on Democritus which you cite appears to mistakenly attribute fragments to his original text.  For example, the first fragment the article appears to attribute directly to Democritus is DK68B125, which Curd attributes to Galen's *On Medical Experience*.  The next DK68B6-10 are attributed by Curd to Sextus Empiricus' *Against the Mathematician*.  The first DK number to appear in the article DK68A1 is attributed by Curd to Diogenes Laertius *Lives of the Philosophers*.  And similarly for other DK referenced fragments in the SEP article.

Comment: @Jim Thinking more generally, we don't know when scribes stopped copying the presocratics.  However, consider that after the fall of Rome and the destruction of the great Library of Alexandria, Europe was a basket-case for many centuries.  The majority of what we know about ancient Greek philosophy we know because it was preserved by the Islamicate scholars of Persia and the Middle East. The [recovery of Aristotle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery_of_Aristotle) in the 12th/13th Century marked the reintroduction of Greek thought into Europe. What was lost was lost.

Comment: @nwr: Does Curd's book include the fragments or is it a general book on the topic?

Comment: @Jim Yes, Curd's book includes fragments - in fact it is probably 90% fragments.  Each philosopher is given a chapter which begins with some brief introductory comments by Curd followed by a selection of fragments relating to their works.  It is really meant as a reference text, not as a commentary itself. The book proceeds chronologically, beginning with Thales and ending with Antiphon.

Comment: @nwr: Are the translations good? From what I know there are a very large amount of translations and many times the translation is "biased" based on the personal favorite interpretation of the translator. That's why I was mainly interested in mathematicians and physicists. Also does it include the original text to show how close the translation is?

Comment: @Jim When issues of translation occur, Curd provides translators notes - usually as a brief footnote.  The commentary is minimal.  If you are interested in this area, I would recommend a text with more commentary such as [The Oxford Handbook of Presocratic Philosophy](https://www.amazon.com/Oxford-Handbook-Presocratic-Philosophy-Handbooks/dp/0199837554/ref=sr_1_3?qid=1649617089&refinements=p_27%3APatricia+Curd&s=books&sr=1-3&text=Patricia+Curd), of which Curd is an editor and a contributor.

Comment: @nwr: What exactly is this book about? Complementary one?

Comment: @Jim It's a compendium of papers written by different specialist academics working in the field.  It includes a mixture of papers, some concerning the writings of a particular philosopher, others concerning particular subjects such as time, space, and matter.  There is also an introduction chapter concerning historiographical issues.  Check out the preview on Amazon for a better overview.  Reading and research into the presocratics is highly specialized and with a limited audience.  I only found myself reading a small bit about it by chance.